SAML SSO Test Integration with ITFoxTech and MockSAML
I need to create and test a SAML SSO workflow using a test SAML Identity Provider (IDP) utilizing .NET 4.7 with an MVC Web application.  My scenario is that I will be integrating with a custom IDP for which I do not currently have the details, however, I need to begin creating the SSO workflow for testing so that we can later integrate with the actual provider.
My requirements were:

Find a SAML Library which would work with .NET 4.7 MVC
Find a test IDP that will allow me to mock requests for workflow testing (lots of questions mention tools that are no longer available)

I did not find any questions that showed all the pieces of the integration with a mock provider along with the tools to use so I'm creating this question to post the solution I found to hopefully help others.  If others have found additional solutions then feel free to post as well.

You can both use ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0 as relaying party and identity provider.

Identity provider sample in ASP.NET Core
Relaying party sample in ASP.NET framework 4.7

By looking at the relaying party example in .NET framework  4.8, it should be possible to convert the identity provider example to .NET framework 4.8.

Thank you for sharing Anders!  This was really helpful when I got to the next phase of getting the session token created.  I was able to use the Relaying Party sample to figure out the other pieces of the federated authentication configuration.

There are other providers but the ones that I found that I was able to integrate successfully were:

ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Mvc - provides the .NET SAML Library
MockSAML.com - provides the SAML 2.0 test IDP

Step 1 - Get MockSAML Details

Go to https://mocksaml.com/namespace/ChangeThisToWhateverYouLike
The URL after namespace can be changed to whatever you wish to use for testing.
This page will give you the pieces that you need for your SAML Library configuration: IDPMetadata URL, Issuer/EntityID, SSO Url

Step 2 - Add ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Mvc

However you manage your packages (Nuget Package Manager, etc.), add ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Mvc to the project. We will configure this via the web.config with the test IDP data we got in Step 1

Step 3 - Update your web.config

Insert the following settings into the <appSettings> block of your web.config.  They should match whatever you got in Step 1.



<add key="Saml2:IdPMetadata" value="https://mocksaml.com/api/namespace/test/saml/metadata" /> 
<add key="Saml2:Issuer" value="https://saml.example.com/entityid/test" />
<add key="Saml2:SingleSignOnDestination" value="https://mocksaml.com/api/namespace/test/saml/sso"/> 
<add key="Saml2:SignatureAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" /> 
<add key="Saml2:CertificateValidationMode" value="None" />



Step 4 - Add Controller to handle SAML Auth

Add the following controller which you will use within your application to redirect to the test IDP and then have it send you back to your application. This controller can be further tweaked and is simply meant as a very basic integration test between the .NET Saml Library and the test IDP. You may want to go to this action via the user clicking a Sign-In link. You may need to perform additional authorization logic specific to your applications security in the AssertionConsumerService action. This is just meant to get you started.



using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Mvc;
using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Schemas;
using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IdentityModel.Services;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Test.Web.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class SamlAuthController : Controller
    {
        const string relayStateReturnUrl = "ReturnUrl";
        private readonly Saml2Configuration config;

        public SamlAuthController()
        {
            config = IdentityConfig.Saml2Configuration;
        }

        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            string acsURL = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~/SamlAuth/AssertionConsumerService"));
            var binding = new Saml2RedirectBinding();
            binding.SetRelayStateQuery(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { relayStateReturnUrl, returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/") }
            });

            return binding.Bind(new Saml2AuthnRequest(config)
            {
                AssertionConsumerServiceUrl = new Uri(acsURL)
            }).ToActionResult();
        }

        public ActionResult AssertionConsumerService()
        {
            var httpRequest = Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(validate: true);
            var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(config);

            httpRequest.Binding.ReadSamlResponse(httpRequest, saml2AuthnResponse);
            if (saml2AuthnResponse.Status != Saml2StatusCodes.Success)
            {
                throw new AuthenticationException($"SAML Response status: {saml2AuthnResponse.Status}");
            }
            httpRequest.Binding.Unbind(httpRequest, saml2AuthnResponse);

            var relayStateQuery = httpRequest.Binding.GetRelayStateQuery();
            var returnUrl = relayStateQuery.ContainsKey(relayStateReturnUrl) ? relayStateQuery[relayStateReturnUrl] : Url.Content("~/");
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

    }
}



Most examples online are when you have a valid certificate issued by your IDP.  However, when testing a mock IDP, you may not have a valid cert.  Removing the certificate settings from the web.config, as is done in this example, will allow ITfoxtech to ignore that.  Leaving it in there with a certificate that is not valid will lead to errors.
Also, you have to set the AssertionConsumerServiceUrl in the binding.Bind so that the ACSUrl gets correctly set in the query string so that the authentication workflow will direct back to your site.
Took a bit of trial and error to figure out those pieces so hopefully it helps someone else.
